# NodeJs upload with Form-Data

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data, multer

I need to send file and userCode with POST request:

I'm using form-data type like this:
[image]

I want to uploadimage after some control, so I wrote post method like this:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './images/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname); 
    },
  });
  
  const upload = multer({ storage: storage
   
});
    app.post('/uploadimage',function (req, res) { 
        let userCode = req.body.userID
        console.log("Body:",req.body.userID)
        checkUserField(userCode,config.number, async(err,userData)=> { 
            if(err){
                return res.status(500).json({message: err}); 
            }
            upload.single('file')(req, res, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).json({message: err}); //file upload error
                }
                res.send('Image Upload:' + fileUrl);
            })
        })    
       
    });
```

When I use like this: req.body.userCode return undefined.
I need to send more than one info and check something before upload,
If I use like this:
`app.post('/uploadimage', upload.single('file'),function (req, res) { }` it works but data already upload before my control. How can I manage this.

How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Multer's job is to parse `multipart/form-data` request bodies. This includes files and **any other fields**.

You cannot access `req.body` for a `multipart/form-data` request until Multer has parsed the values out, just like `req.file` / `req.files`.

If you want to discard the file based on other field validation, you could always delete it

```js
import { unlink } from "node:fs/promises";
// or if not using modules
// const { unlink } = require("node:fs/promises");

app.post("/uploadimage", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  const { userCode } = req.body;
  
  checkUserField(userCode, config.number, async (err, userData) => {
    if (err) {
      try {
        await unlink(req.file.path);
      } catch (unlinkErr) {
        console.warn(unlinkErr);
      }
      return res.status(422).json({ message: err });
    }
    res.send(`Image Upload: ${fileUrlFromSomewhere}`);
  });
});
```

---

> but data already upload before my control

This is how requests work. By the time Express has received and routed the request, the entire upload process has already happened.

Comment: Thank you for your reply So how can I check first with a request I sent with form data and upload it?

Comment: Actually, i need to some control before the uploading process

Comment: @hobik that would need to happen client-side

Comment: On the mobile side, the user will select an image and press the upload button, a single query will come to me with the userCode and file in it. I have to do the control on this side. Because I'm looking at the database.

Comment: @hobik I've updated my answer to show how you can delete the uploaded file if validation fails. The alternative is to make two requests... 1) validate the `userCode`, then 2) upload the file